# Why did my pointer to a std::vector's element change its value after push_back()?

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector

I use a simple code:

```
std::vector < float > arr = { 3.42f, 6.45f, 53.43f };
float *elemPtr;
elemPtr = &arr[ 0 ];

std::cout << "elemPtr = " << *elemPtr << std::endl;
arr.push_back( 7.0f );
std::cout << "elemPtr = " << *elemPtr << std::endl;
```

And that code produces me following output:

```
elemPtr = 3.42
elemPtr = -6.25982e+18
```

Why does it happening after push_back? I didn't remove the first element of the vector. Why does it works like this?

I use Clang compiler (Xcode).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`push_back` invalidates pointers, references, and iterators to existing elements.

That's because of the contiguity guarantee.  `push_back` increases the size of the vector, and if the capacity of the internal buffer isn't sufficient to hold a new item immediately after the existing ones, in order to maintain contiguity, they all have to be moved to a new larger buffer.

If you want to continue accessing an element after future calls to `push_back`, your options are to access it by index in a vector, or use a container with no contiguity guarantee, such as `std::list`.

Answer (score 6):

The vector's storage got reallocated (to accommodate more elements in one contiguous block), invalidating all the pointers (and iterators).

Learn more about this here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back

> If the new `size()` is greater than `capacity()` then all iterators and references (including the past-the-end iterator) are invalidated. Otherwise only the past-the-end iterator is invalidated.